# cli.js require('@reat-native-community/cli') cannot find module

Tags: react-native

Upgrading to react-native v0.59.9.

Receive `Cannot find module '../@react-native-community/cli'` at `/node_modules/react-native/cli.js:12:11` when attempting to build release version with command `node node_modules/react-native/cli.js bundle --platform android --dev false --reset-cache --entry-file index.js --bundle-output /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Build-Deploy-Mobile-App-Android/workspace/src/mobile/Tresta/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle --assets-dest /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Build-Deploy-Mobile-App-Android/workspace/src/mobile/Tresta/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release`

Deleted node_modules directory to solve different problem, and did an npm install.

Can execute `react-native run-android` locally.

The line is `var cli = require('@react-native-community/cli');`

@react-native-community is at same directory level at react-native.

I do not see anything in the @react-native-community/cli directory that require could load :

````
jest.config.js  node_modules  package.json  README.md  setup_env.sh  testSetup.js```

 react-native info
info 
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.5
      CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4850HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz
      Memory: 118.64 MB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 8.15.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/bin/node
      npm: 6.9.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.7.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.2, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
        Build Tools: 23.0.1, 23.0.3, 25.0.0, 25.0.2, 26.0.1, 27.0.3, 28.0.3
        System Images: android-24 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-25 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-25 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-25 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 10.2.1/10E1001 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6 
      react-native: 0.59.9 => 0.59.9 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
      react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
      react-native: 0.59.9
````

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. Was told to .gitignore build directories. Obviously react-native-community/cli needs its build directory.